# uicollectionview cell background image comes repetadely

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

in my app i am using collectionview.so i am using model and insert response array in model and set perticular image in perticular cell. and its showing perfectly while collection view is load but when i scroll images getting change images are loading at the place where i dont want to display it and its continue changing.

here is my code

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell : seat_cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("seat_cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! seat_cell
    let data : SeatDetailModel = get_seat_detail.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! SeatDetailModel


    if (data.KoltukStr == "PI") || (data.KoltukStr == "MA") || (data.KoltukStr == "SA") || (data.KoltukStr == "KA") || (data.KoltukStr == "KO")
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.lblname.text = ""
    }

    else
    {
        cell.lblname.text = data.KoltukStr


        if (data.DurumYan == "2") && (data.Durum == "0")
        {
            //cell.img_seat.image = UIImage(named: "seat_men")
            //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "seat_men")!)
            cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "seat_men"))

        }
        else if (data.DurumYan == "1") && (data.Durum == "0")
        {


            cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "seat_lady"))
        }
        else if (data.Durum == "0")
        {

            cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "seat_green"))
        }
        else
        {

            cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "blank_seat"))
        }
    }
    return cell
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell : seat_cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("seat_cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! seat_cell
    let data : SeatDetailModel = get_seat_detail.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! SeatDetailModel

    if (Gender.isEmpty)
    {
        alertViewShow(self, title: "Alert", message: "Please Select Gender before Seat Selection")
    }
    else
    {

         cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "seat_lady"))

    }
   [![This is the screen which load when collectionview load this is perfect][1]][1]

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return get_seat_detail.count
}
```

[image: this is the view which i got while i scroll uicollectionview]

in image you can show view which i got while scrolling. but when initially collectionview load its showing perfect means its not showing the seat without number which was perfect

Comment: This is because cells are reused while scrolling, set image in both condition. When image is not needed set nil to backgroundview

Comment: sorry but i am confused can you please post a code line @Savitha

Comment: if (data.KoltukStr == "PI") || (data.KoltukStr == "MA") || (data.KoltukStr == "SA") || (data.KoltukStr == "KA") || (data.KoltukStr == "KO")
    {
        cell.backgroundView = nil
    }else
    { // set image based on condition}

Comment: thanks @Savitha its worked for me. i just spend to much time in this silly mistakes. btw you save my time thanks

Comment: hello @Savitha but my image is not changing in didSelectItemAtIndexPath what should i do?

Comment: There also you are missing setting image in both condition ( if and else )

Comment: @Savitha its not working for image change give me some solution if its possible

Comment: In didSelectItemAtIndexPath method you should get cell by using cellAtIndexpath not by dequeue method

Comment: can you attach screenshot of what is not working

Comment: now its working. your answer help me to find out my problem. i just changed cellAtIndexpath instead of dequeue method and its works for me. Thanks @Savitha

Comment: if possible can you please give me the solution of this question? @Savitha  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35499988/collectionview-change-cell-background-image-when-scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Your cell is getting reused, When ever you are creating new cell always clear the values for cell items, In below method

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell : seat_cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("seat_cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! seat_cell // After this line
    cell.backgroundView = UIImageView() // clear old references
```

add this line for default imageview, this will wipe out old references.

Comment: thanks @prabhu but now problem is image is not getting change in didSelectItemAtIndexPath

Comment: if (Gender.isEmpty) succeeds or not?

Comment: if (Gender.isEmpty) will succeeds it will popup alertview. else it will change cell background color