# collectionview change cell background image when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, swift2

hi i am using collectionview in my app. and its working well when i select any cell i just change background image of that cell. but when i scroll collection view that changed background image automatically change to the default image. thats my issue.

here is my code

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell : seat_cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("seat_cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! seat_cell
    cell.backgroundView = UIImageView()
    let data : SeatDetailModel = get_seat_detail.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! SeatDetailModel


    if (data.KoltukStr == "PI") || (data.KoltukStr == "MA") || (data.KoltukStr == "SA") || (data.KoltukStr == "KA") || (data.KoltukStr == "KO")
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.lblname.text = ""
        cell.backgroundView = nil
    }

    else
    {
        cell.lblname.text = data.KoltukStr


        if (data.DurumYan == "2") && (data.Durum == "0")
        {

            cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "seat_men"))
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = true
        }
        else if (data.DurumYan == "1") && (data.Durum == "0")
        {


           cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "seat_lady"))
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = true
        }
        else if (data.Durum == "0")
        {

            //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "seat_green")!)
            cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "seat_green"))
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = true
        }
        else
        {

            if (data.Durum == "1") || (data.Durum == "3") || (data.Durum == "5")
            {
                cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "blank_seat"))
                cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
            }
            else
            {
                cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "blank_seat"))
            }


        }
    }
    return cell
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell : seat_cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! seat_cell
    let data : SeatDetailModel = get_seat_detail.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! SeatDetailModel

    if (Gender.isEmpty)
    {
        alertViewShow(self, title: "Alert", message: "Please Select Gender before Seat Selection")

    }
    else
    {
       seatcount = seatcount + 1

        if (data.DurumYan == "1") && (data.Durum == "0")
        {
            cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "seat_lady_checked"))
            selectedseat = true
        }
        else if (data.DurumYan == "2") && (data.Durum == "0")
        {
            cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "seat_men_checked"))
            selectedseat = true
        }
        else if (data.Durum == "0")
        {
           cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "seat_green_checked"))
            selectedseat = true
        }

    }

    print(data.KoltukStr)

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return get_seat_detail.count
}
```

[image]

this is the image of when collection view load and i select one cell. but when i scroll all my selected cell background comes to default. so how can i solve that. what i want is cell background must be selected if i select any cell even after scrolling collection view

Comment: store index of selected cell in some array and than check that in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` that array contains current index or not and set image accordingly.

Comment: sorry but can you please give me a line of code for that? @EICaptain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maintain state of each seat like selected or not. based on state you need to set image in cellForItemAtIndexPath

```
if (data.DurumYan == "2") && (data.Durum == "0")
                {
                    var image:UIImage?
                    if selected == true
                    {

                        //image =  selected image
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // image = non selected image
                    }

                    cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: image!)
                    cell.userInteractionEnabled = true
                }
```

Comment: allready tried this. but this will result in all the seat are selected when scrolling

Comment: how are you maintaining state?

Comment: you can maintain state in SeatDetailModel

Comment: thanks a ton @Savitha i just maintain state in model and its work for me. going to upvote your answer you deserve it

Answer (score -1):

Use this in Your  collectionView Datasource Method ...
you are getting this problem when collection view scrooling here is solution try this !!

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.background.image=nil;
cell.background.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"];

}
```